# Editing XML, Preserving Structure and Comments

Tags: php, xml

How can I change the content some nodes in an XML file programmatically using PHP?

The important point is, that the file contains **comments and white-spaces**, which should be **preserved**.

Example of the file:

```
<!-- my config -->
<config>
    <global>
    <install>
        <date/>
    </install>
    <resources>
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host>localhost</host>
                <username/>
                <password/>
                <dbname>foo</dbname>
                <!-- <dbname>bar</dbname> -->
                <model>mysql4</model>

...
```

Comment: You didn't really ask a question, but you can both use the `DOM` or `SimpleXML` to do this.

Comment: 5k reputation, you should know SO rules better... your question is too vague and doesn't show any effort. What have you done so far?

Comment: I would use a text editor. Or do you need to do this programatically?

Comment: [Parsing and processing HTML/XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/parsing-and-processing-html-xml) and [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic)

Comment: @LarsH: programatically of course :-) *edit*

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro: It was too hot yesterday... edited the question ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is using SimpleXmlElement. You can load your xml, modify tags and save it as a new xml again.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php) is some good examples about it.

Comment: Okay I totally did not consider the option SimpleXml loading and exporting it via `asXML()` does preserve comments. That totally works.